# Relative file path in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have written a stored procedure which uses bulk insert to load data from a *.csv file.
It works fine when I mention the physical path.Now I want to use the same stored procedure in a SQL server project.Hence I have to mention the relative path.Is there anyway I can do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It will be good if you also provide your SP

Comment: I know you can handle this with BULK INSERT, but SSIS is really a place were dynamic file naming shines.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to either pass the root in as a parameter to the SP, or have a config table in your DB and set the root path there.  Heck, you might as well just pass in the entire fully qualified name of the file if you can.

Comment: Hi wagregg thanks for the reply.The problem is our codebase is hosted on github and everyone might clone it to different paths. Hence cannot give the absolute path.

Comment: Then I would think adding it as a parameter would be your best bet.  The code responsible for invoking the SP should be responsible for knowing where the input file is located.